# How to run SFML in CLion, Error undefined reference to?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, sfml, clion

I'm new to C++ and try to learn game programming, I choose SFML and run on CLion by Jetbrain and using Ubuntu machine. I following this tutorial [SFML and Linux](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php)  here my code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main() {

RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML Work!");
CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen()) {
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

When I run on CLion it error

```
CMakeFiles/SFMLBasic.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main': 
undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
...
undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'
```

How I config or setup to run SFML in CLion, I don't know CMAKE can do that? I only run by terminal, **It work if I run this command.**

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
./sfml-app
```

How to config to use all reference variable without do manual every time in Terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link SFML library in your CMakeLists.txt.

Have a look at CMake [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html).

And [this link](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) may be helpful for you to know how to find SFML library path in CMake.

Here is a FindSFML.cmake module: https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake

Comment: I just see I accidentally to log in another account. This question was create by me, after read your suggestion I try to fixed and it's work perfect, Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

After read @Stackia suggestion. This is my solution refer to this tutorial [Tutorial: Build your SFML project with CMake](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake)

1. Create a `cmake_modules` folder and download this file [FindSFML.cmake](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake) and copy in it.
2. Edit `CMakeLists.txt` by add this to the end file, click Reload changes.

```
 # Define sources and executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "MySFML")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp)
```

```
# Detect and add SFML
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

3. Now you can select Executable Name `MySFML` and click Run (Shift+F10). It Work!
   [image]

Comment: I'd also add `${SFML_DEPENDENCIES}`. It won't do anything (bad) when linking shared and will automatically add all of SFML's dependencies when switching to static linking.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed it with following steps:

1. Download `http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3.2/64-Linux`

   And extract it in folder with my project:

   ```
   /home/user/ClionProjects/CPP_first/
   ```
2. Named project "CPP_first"
3. `main.cpp` contains following

   ```
   #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

   int main()
   {
       sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
       sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
       shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

       while (window.isOpen())
       {
           sf::Event event;
           while (window.pollEvent(event))
           {
               if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                   window.close();
           }

           window.clear();
           window.draw(shape);
           window.display();
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. `CMakeLists.txt` contain following:

   ```
   set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "CPP_first")
   add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp)


   # Detect and add SFML
   set(SFML_DIR "/home/user/ClionProjects/CPP_first/SFML-2.3.2/share/SFML/cmake/Modules")
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/home/user/ClionProjects/CPP_first/SFML-2.3.2/share/SFML/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
   find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
   if(SFML_FOUND)
       include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
       target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
   endif()
   ```
5. Path to my project `/home/user/ClionProjects/CPP_first/`

PS: I didn't find how to find SFML when it is installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

I hope it will help someone

Answer (score 2):

This is become much simpler now (see this [SFML forum discussion](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0)).
That's what I did to make my sfml project running in clion:

1. Added `C:\SFML\bin` to my env variable `Path`
2. Modified `CMakeLists.txt` of my clion's project:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
   project(Hello_SFML)

   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

   find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
   add_executable(Hello_SFML main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(Hello_SFML sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
   ```

Comment: This worked perfectly on Linux. SFML installed with `sudo apt install libsfml-dev`. On Linux you don't even need step 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you install SFML by:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

you'll find the path in /usr/share/SFML/