# Linker problem with vcpkg and CMake in windows-VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sfml, vcpkg

I'm tring to build vcpkg ports based code in VSCode. (I'm using it with the CMake tool and CMake For Visual Studio Code tool.) But some libraries don't build, such as sfml etc.

My source file is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        sf::Window m_w;
    }
```

I have two very similar CMakeList.txt version and as expected I have two different problem
first CMakeList.txt version

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include(CTest)
enable_testing()
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp)
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION)
include(CPack)
target_include_directories( HelloWorld PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE FLAC OpenAL OpenGL Vorbis)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

and its cmake output

```
[main] Configuring folder: HelloWorld_cmake 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -GNinja -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" -Hd:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake -Bd:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0 with MSVC-like command-line
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0 with MSVC-like command-line
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Found SFML 2.5.1 in D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/share/sfml
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: D:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[main] Building folder: HelloWorld_cmake HelloWorld
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build --config Release --target HelloWorld -- -j 14
[build] [1/2  50% :: 0.235] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/HelloWorld.cpp.obj 
[build] C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe  /nologo -TP -DFLAC__NO_DLL -DOV_EXCLUDE_STATIC_CALLBACKS -I. /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -MD /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\ -c ..\HelloWorld.cpp
[build] ..\HelloWorld.cpp(4,10): fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
[build] #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
[build]          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] 1 error generated.
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

Second is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
project(HelloWorld VERSION 0.0.0.0)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()
find_package(OpenAL CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp)
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION)
include(CPack)
target_include_directories( HelloWorld PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE OpenAL::OpenAL)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE FLAC OpenAL OpenGL Vorbis)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

```
[main] Configuring folder: HelloWorld_cmake 
[main] Configuring folder: HelloWorld_cmake 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -GNinja -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" -Hd:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake -Bd:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Found SFML 2.5.1 in D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/share/sfml
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: D:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[main] Building folder: HelloWorld_cmake HelloWorld
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build --config Release --target HelloWorld -- -j 14
[build] [1/2  50% :: 0.673] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj
[build] [2/2 100% :: 0.711] Linking CXX executable HelloWorld.exe
[build] FAILED: HelloWorld.exe 
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj  /out:HelloWorld.exe /implib:HelloWorld.lib /pdb:HelloWorld.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console  D:\repositories\VS\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\lib\OpenAL32.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\repositories\VS_Code\HelloWorld_cmake\build && powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary D:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build/HelloWorld.exe -installedDir D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/bin -OutVariable out""
[build] LINK: command "C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj /out:HelloWorld.exe /implib:HelloWorld.lib /pdb:HelloWorld.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console D:\repositories\VS\vcpkg-master\installed\x64-windows\lib\OpenAL32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:HelloWorld.exe.manifest" failed (exit code 1) with the following output:
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl sf::Window::Window(void)
[build] >>> referenced by CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj:(main)
[build] 
[build] lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl sf::Window::~Window(void)
[build] >>> referenced by CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj:(main)
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

In this version, OpenAL is represent. When this changes (such glfw. It does not matter),the error in this version does not change.

if I dont use sfml,however if I use different package such as SDL, any error is not occour .

For exemple,
Source is

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

    // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );

    // Check that the window was successfully created
    if (window == NULL) {
        // In the case that the window could not be made...
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // The window is open: could enter program loop here (see SDL_PollEvent())

    SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example

    // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeList is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/repositories/VS/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
project(HelloWorld VERSION 0.0.0.0)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()
find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp)
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION)
include(CPack)
target_include_directories( HelloWorld PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
```

CMake output is

```
[main] Configuring folder: HelloWorld_cmake 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -GNinja -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" -Hd:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake -Bd:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: D:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[main] Building folder: HelloWorld_cmake HelloWorld
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/repositories/VS_Code/HelloWorld_cmake/build --config Release --target HelloWorld -- -j 14
[build] [1/2  50% :: 0.137] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\HelloWorld.cpp.obj
[build] [2/2 100% :: 0.606] Linking CXX executable HelloWorld.exe
[build] lld-link: warning: found both wmain and main; using latter
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

There is no error. This is fully work.

Finally, how can I fix these problems? Why are these problems occur.

Comment: It doesn't look like you *link* the SFML libraries to your executable `HelloWorld` anywhere in your CMake file. Have you seen how this is done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602471/how-to-run-sfml-in-clion-error-undefined-reference-to) post or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931667/undefined-reference-to-sfml) post? You need to link the SFML libraries using `${SFML_LIBRARIES}`.

Comment: Yes,I have seen both of post. `target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE FLAC OpenAL OpenGL Vorbis)` this is the mantioned command in this postes. I tried like that but not worked(these are same thing, vcpkg is making for us many thing). Helloworld is generated in build folder(this is change with your compiler but whole compiler result is same). cmake found the SFML file. Sometimes VSCode(I know this is not the subject) cannot see SFML but cmake can see.@squareskittles

Comment: "*I tried like that but not worked*"... what *specifically* happens when you try adding the line `target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE ${SFML_LIBRARIES})` to the end of your CMake file? Do you receive the same error message? A different error message? It is hard to help without knowing what **specific** error you are seeing...

Comment: @squareskittles the result is same. I got same error. `lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl sf::Window::~Window(void)` this error is from clang -msvc. With other compiler, occur same(in the this post) error.

Comment: Ok, does your CMake run to completion? Does it successfully find the SFML package and its components? It would helpful if you could add the *full* CMake output to your question post, including the command you use to run CMake. The linker output would also be helpful so we can see what is *actually* being linked.

Comment: I added full cmake output.

Comment: This is helpful, but something doesn't add up. The libraries you link in CMake (i.e. glfw, FLAC, OpenAL, etc.) are not listed in the link command in your build output. Instead, it looks like you are linking `SDL2.lib` in the linker output. Are you sure you posted the correct output that corresponds to the CMake file in your question?

Comment: Problem is same(and sfml is same during this time) but cmakelist and src file is not same. I added or removed some library in this files for test. I changed to compiler. Unfortunatly, nothing is change

Comment: Unless you are linking the SFML libraries, you will continue to receive the error mentioned in your post. Unfortunately, it is difficult to understand the differences between your provided CMake code, and the provided build log (which appears to be from a different project). It would be best if you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this issue, providing all of the same information for that.

Comment: My problem is that, Not linking to my Helloworld file with lld-link error. But it is not depend to other used library. When I removed them, and only added to SFML command, I'm taking same error. Only changed thing is linked lib file but sfml is doesnt link in every situation and give to me same error :D @squareskittles thank you for your effort :)

Comment: "When I removed them, and only added to SFML command, I'm taking same error. Only changed thing is linked lib file but sfml is doesnt link in every situation and give to me same error" - This is quite **vague** description of the changes in the code. And taking into account misusing of terms in your question post and comments, I can hardly imagine what this description **actually** means. Please, do not *describe* the code, **show** it instead (add to the question post).

Comment: I'm going to edit this post. @Tsyvarev

Comment: I see no `sfml` in the linker command line and I guess that SFML package provided by vcpkg simply doesn't set `SFML_LIBRARIES` variable. You may check a value of this variable by printing it via `message()` command. Instead of `SFML_LIBRARIES` variable try to use IMPORTED targets, as described in [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406388/setup-cmake-with-sfml-in-vs2017#comment97877991_47408270).

Comment: `if(SFML_FOUND) message( SFML_LIBRARIES ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ) endif()`output of this command is `[build] SFML_LIBRARIES` . In my opinnion, you are right. How can I fix this.Or how can ı learn to fix this :) Thank you for your reply @Tsyvarev. -edit- -> your second option is give to me same issue

Comment: Please, update the question post (the code and the error log) when you use IMPORTED targets of sfml, not `SFML_LIBRARIES` variable.

Comment: Sorry for that, I cant change now. Dont ask to me why :) In different situation,I found out similar issue. In this case when I wrote some print library and add that with `add_library(hello_lib SHARED hello.hpp hello.cpp)`, occur `undefined symbol: public: __cdecl ` error. In other case, add library with static. no issue occur.In my opinnion, this is dll issue with my cmake but I dont know.